# How to generate genesis file for fantom-foundation repo?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, genesis, fantom

I gonna to build my own blockchain network by using Fantom network source project.

I can't know what content is there in fantom network genesis file.

Is there any document for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can download genesis file by `wget https://opera.fantom.network/mainnet.g`

It's mentioned [here](https://docs.fantom.foundation/staking/how-to-run-a-validator-node#register-fantom-validator) in official document.

Also, you may find [this](https://docs.ankr.com/nodes/fantom-full-node) guide helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to export the genesis file from a running Opera node:

```
opera --datadir=demo/opera1.datadir export genesis my-genesis-file.g
```

**However this will not help you to start your own new network.**

As stated in https://github.com/Fantom-foundation/lachesis_launch/blob/master/docs/launch-private-network.md :

> Launching a production private network involves generation of a custom genesis file.
>
> Once genesis file is in place, all the instructions for Opera mainnet/testnet will apply to your private network with the only exception that users have to use the custom genesis file instead of Opera mainnet or testnet genesis files.
>
> Currently, there's no tool for generation of a go-opera genesis file. If you're looking to implement one yourself, check out the functions https://github.com/Fantom-foundation/go-opera/blob/9f7c98f501143b5775a34796b34c9495473bf8d1/opera/genesisstore/dump.go#L71 and https://github.com/Fantom-foundation/go-opera/blob/9f7c98f501143b5775a34796b34c9495473bf8d1/integration/makegenesis/genesis.go#L44.